# Display popup when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, colorbox

I'm using colorbox and wanted to know if you know any way to display the popup when the visitor is scrolling the site.

I know it's possible to display the popup when the page loads and to display the popup after X seconds. But that does not help me.

I saw some websites that display the popup when the visitor scrolls down the page.

How to do it?

Comment: Step 1. Code something. Step 2. Read their source code. Step 3. Apply code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [jQuery Waypoints plugin](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   //open popup
});
```

The scroll event will call whenever the user scrolls.